# How to pass multiple records in REST API POST method using JSON body

Tags: json, rest, salesforce, integration, apex

I have a requirement where I need to create multiple records in my custom object using REST API POST method.
Now the problem is I am able to create one record at a time and I am not able to create multiple records in one REST API call. I have found on net by passing JSON request body i will be able to create multiple records. 
I am completely new to integration and don't understand how to create mutilple records in one REST API call and how can i pass JSON request body in my REST API.

Can somebody help me in achiving my requirement please.
Here I am posting my code for reference:

```
@HttpPost
    global static ID createAddress(String Address, String City, String FirstName, String LastName, String Phone, String Email
                                       ) {
        //First find the contact id matching the email.
        String ContactId = [SELECT Id
                              FROM Contact
                              WHERE Email = :Email].Id;
        //Second post the new ListofAddresses to the owner of the email.                                 
        Address__c thisAddress = new Address__c(
            Contact__c=ContactId,
            Address__c=Address,
            City__c=City,
            First_Name__c=FirstName,
            Last_Name__c=LastName,
            Phone__c=Phone,

        ); 
              /* List<Address__c> result = [SELECT Address__c, City__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Phone__c
                                   FROM Address__c
                                WHERE Contact__c = :ContactId];                          
           if(result.size() > 0){
            return null;
             }else{*/
          insert thisAddress;
          return thisAddress.Id;

             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for passing multiple record using the Json format

@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
    global  class MyRestResource {

```
    @HttpPost
    webService static String doPost() {
        Account account = new Account();
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        List<jsonWrap> jsonWrapList = (List<jsonWrap>)JSON.deserialize(req.requestbody.tostring(),List<jsonWrap>.class);
        return 'Account Success';
    }

    public class jsonWrap{
        String Namex;
        String phonex;
        String websitex;
    }
}
```

Sample Json

[
  {
    "Namex": "test1",
    "phonex": "12312",
    "websitex": "test.com"
  },
  {
    "Namex": "test2",
    "phonex": "12312",
    "websitex": "test.com"
  },
  {
    "Namex": "test2",
    "phonex": "12312",
    "websitex": "test.com"
  }
]